# Finding number of variables occurrences and numbering them

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I create a column that assigns the nth number of occurrences of the variables on another column. Used `COUNTIF($A$2:A2;A2)` in `excel` to achieve results in column 2 on attached `IMG`

[image]

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results seem to rely on ordering, but you have no column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Tables don't contains variables either.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.

You can use `row_number()` for the enumeration, but you need a column or expression for the ordering.  For instance, by date of birth:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by emp_number order by date_of_birth) as emp_id
from t;
```

Comment: Is it possible to determine the nth occurrence of every single entry under Emp_Number (unordered set). Then populate the output on another column as;1 for the first occurrence;2 2nd occurrence; 3 3rd occurrence ....

Comment: @TVTango . . .  That is what `row_number()` does.